# Blender is eating GB's of HD space when rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, osx

Blender is eating GB's of HD space when rendering.
Its uses up around 5GB for a few hundred frames of animation and doesn't release it after its finished.
I gather this may have been because I had cache BVH ticked.

I'm on osx 10.9 but can't for the life of me find any BVH files?
How do i find them on a Mac, or is my problem elsewhere?

Comment: It usually does this when working with physics/particles etc. And yes, it doesn't release(Read delete) the cache afterwards.

There is only one workaround to it. use specific area of hd for cache and delete it after usage. 

A system with 1000k particles, or fluid with 96 res can easily take up 5 gb of space

Answer (score 1):

The bvh cache files can be found in a folder called cache that will be located in the same folder as the config folder that contains `startup.blend`, the filenames start with `bvh_` followed by a unique 32 character string.

See [this page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout) for details about where the config folder can be found.

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9291/935) has more info on when the BVH Cache can be helpful.