# Is it safe to delete the cache?

Tags: path, cache

Does deleting the cache files in the *USER* directory hurt anything?
The user directory where the cache in question is:

```
{username}\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.70\cache
```

Also is cycles what is generating this cache?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9291/599

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, cycles caches BVH ([Bounding Volume Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy)) files in there when *Cache BVH* is enabled in *Render settings > Performance*:

[image]

Deleting them shouldn't do anything bad. Cycles will just regenerate these files (though it won't cache them if you disable *Cache BVH*), which might cause an increase in render times, depending on the complexity of your scene.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the name of the caches should have helped me guess what it is though :p