# Render farm: is "pack all" all I need or should I do something more?

Tags: rendering, export, linked-data, baking

I need to send scenes to a render farm, and I know there's an option called "pack all" which saves all the external data into the .blend file.

But is that enough? I was reading about cache files, and I don't know if that's included, or if I have to do something more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a simple example, what you suggest should, for the most part, be good.

I'd also like to add the following:

- Select `Make Paths Relative` in case someone wants to unpack the `.blend` file at a different location.
- Double check your output directory.  Does it need to be set to a relative path? Does that path actually exist?
- If you're learning in this environment, it's good to test out your render by only rendering the first few frames with a low sample rate and smaller image size so you can get quick feedback in case something goes wrong.
- The `bvh_*` cache files can become quite large.  If your home directory has a small quota, and you have a scratch environment or another drive you can dump them on, then the solution seems to be to remove the cache folder and link it to that other space.

On *nix systems, the cache folder is:
 `~/.config/blender/<blenderversion>/cache`

On Mac, the cache folder is:
`~/Library/Application Support/Blender/<blenderversion>/cache`

On Windows, I'm not so sure, and I don't know how it changes from one version to the next.

You might want to read through this Blender Stack Exchange entry as well:
[How can I change the directory used to cache BVM](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9291/how-can-i-change-the-directory-used-to-cache-bvh)

Comment: Thanks.I'd like to add something I just discovered.  If you don't have 'Cache BVH' checked in the render settings, you won't be generating the aforementioned 'bvh_*' files and your cache shouldn't be filling up.  Though I 've not tested this out yet with running in batch mode, I just discovered it while rendering through the GUI.