# What does static/dynamic BVH do?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, performance

In the *render properties* panel, under the *performance* rollout there is a setting for *static vs. dynamic BVH*.  I am simply wondering what this setting does.

From the [Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/BVH):

> The raytracing acceleration structure used is a bounding volume hierarchy... This code includes spatial splits to make it more competitive with kd-trees.

Unfortunately, though I know quite a bit about cycles, this is totally Greek to me.

I couldn't really find much else useful on the web other than it may have some impact on animations only.  Can anybody explain this better (maybe starting with BVH in general)?

Comment: Some info here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9313/241

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7510/599

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*About BVH:*

BVH creation is a method of space-partitioning to speed-up ray-tracing (or also collision detection, etc.). BVH itself is a node-tree data structure that wraps polygons in bounding-boxes based on spatial-hierarchy - thus **B**ounding **V**olume **H**ierarchy. You can compare how BVH looks (left) in contrast with Octree (right):

[image]

Space data structures eliminate potential ray intersection candidates by omitting geometric objects in bounding volumes which are not intersected by the current ray. It's still an area of active research (gpu friendly implementations) - there are many more types (kD-tree, BVH, BIH, Octree, Uniform Grid,..) and it often depends on what you need them for.

[Here](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Education/EDAN30/lectures/S2-bvh.pdf) is link (.pdf) for more reading how BVH works for anyone interested.

---

*Now static vs. dynamic option for view-port:*

If you start view-port rendering BVH will be created. When the scene is changed (this counts object movement, geometry deforming, etc.) the static BVH needs to be completely rebuilt resulting in slower update times. But it renders faster. With dynamic BVH only a portion needs to be updated, which results in faster updating but it renders slower.

For rendering only static BVH is used, and the BVH tree can be also cached for faster re-renders (when for example only camera or materials change) or cached for all animation frames for faster re-animations (if that's a word:)