# What is a Point Density texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, point-clouds

I see Blender 2.76 now has a feature called "Point Density" textures. Is this a particle system? If so, how is it different from previous particle systems?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45481/halo-particles-dont-render-in-cycles

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Point Density Textures are a way of rendering particles or mesh vertices as volumetric halos in Cycles.

A halo is basically a little volumetric ball.  You can accomplish essentially the same effect without point clouds by using dupliverts or a particle system with little spheres as particles.  However point density textures are *much* more efficient due to requiring a much simpler [BVH](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32473/5705), since the entire volume is within one object, instead of hundreds of thousands of little overlapping objects.

[image]

The above example uses a particle system with 250,000 particles and a turbulence force field.  To render it as a point cloud I created a "domain" object (a scaled cube) around the particle system and gave it a volumetric emission shader using the *Density* from the Point Density as the emission strength.  See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45487/5705) for how to set up a point density texture.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it is a way of using particles or a mesh's vertices to drive the density of a volumetric material. You will need to use a **Point Density** texture and set the emitter object/mesh.

[image]

[See more on the manual page](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/volume/point_density.html)