# Is Static / Dynamic BVH still present in recent builds of 2.79?

Tags: rendering, performance, bvh

There still is Static / Dynamic BVH dropdown in official 2.79 build:

[image]

That dropdown to choose between them isn't present in recent builds of 2.79 or 2.8 anymore.

[image]

Viewport resolution only seems to be somewhat related though it changes quality of render which is not what I'm looking for.
Here is information about BVH [What does static/dynamic BVH do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32465/what-does-static-dynamic-bvh-do). Practically it allowed to make faster viewport preview renders if no geometry changes were in place (materials setup for example).
Is it still possible to choose between these types of BVH or are options substituted with shown above?

Comment: So apparently it was removed probably in favor of more flexible ways of rendering added in newer versions